Add a text to the margin of a ggplot that includes a chart and a Grob Table
I've create a ggplot plot violin plot and tabulation below the plot as a Grob.
A minimal example in the R code below.
require(tidyverse)
require(gridExtra)

# File name for output

Fl_Nm <- "MyFile.jpg"

# Make a violin plot
Vio_plt <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, 
                               y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
       geom_violin(show.legend = FALSE) +
       labs(title = "Iris data - Sepal Length", caption = Fl_Nm)  

# Make a stats table
Sts_tbl <- iris %>% 
       group_by(Species) %>% 
       summarise(mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
       t()

# Make a graphics object of the table
Sts_Grob <- tableGrob(tbl,                                                   
                      rows = NULL,                                            
                      widths = unit(rep(5,3), c(rep("cm", 3))))

# Create final image
ggsave(filename = Fl_Nm, 
       grid.arrange(Vio_plt, Sts_Grob), 
       device = "jpeg", 
       width = 16, height = 14.5, units = "cm", dpi = 300)

This creates the following combined plot

Note I've include the output file name for future reference as a caption below the violin plot. However I would prefer to have this reference to the output file name included below the Grob, or perhaps in the lower margin of the output image.
How do I achieve this please?

You can use grid::textGrob(Fl_Nm, ...) to create a grob containing just that text.  You'll need to choose the font etc in the ..., and tell grid.arrange where to put it.

Another option would be to switch to patchwork to merge the plot and the table. Doing so allows to add a caption for the patch via plot_annotation:
library(patchwork)

list(Vio_plt + labs(caption = NULL), Sts_Grob) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1) &
  plot_annotation(
    caption = Fl_Nm
  )



One way would be to create a textGrob with the file name and build it into the final file using grid.arrange with a layout matrix to give a bit more control over the final appearance. As suggested by @ user2554330.
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

# File name for output

Fl_Nm <- "MyFile.jpg"

# make a text object for the file name

file_nm_grob <- textGrob(Fl_Nm, just = c("right", "bottom"))


# Make a violin plot
Vio_plt <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, 
                                   y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_violin(show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Iris data - Sepal Length")  

# Make a stats table
Sts_tbl <- iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarise(mean(Sepal.Length)) |> 
  t()

# Make a graphics object of the table
Sts_Grob <- tableGrob(Sts_tbl,                                                   
                      rows = NULL,                                            
                      widths = unit(rep(5,3), c(rep("cm", 3))))

layout_mtx <- rbind(c(1,1,1),
                    c(2,2,2),
                    c(NA,NA,3))

# Create final image
ggsave(filename = Fl_Nm, 
       grid.arrange(grobs = list(Vio_plt, Sts_Grob, file_nm_grob),
                    layout_matrix = layout_mtx,
                    heights = c(6, 4, 0.5)), 
       device = "jpeg", 
       width = 16, height = 14.5, units = "cm", dpi = 300)


Created on 2024-06-09 with reprex v2.0.2
